# What is the equivalent of "npm install" in NuGet?

Tags: nuget, npm

In a Node.js project, I simply distribute a `package.json` file along with the rest of the source files and whoever wants to use this project simply runs

```
npm install
```

and all dependencies are downloaded and placed into `node_modules` directory.

In the world of NuGet, there is a `packages.config` file which seems roughly equivalent to the dependencies section of Node's `package.json`. When I open up `cmd.exe` or PowerShell, what is the command that would do the equivalent of `npm install`?

Comment: [`nuget install`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Install_Command).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
nuget install packages.config
```

[and get NuGet.exe Command Line](http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/222685)